# Simple IF statement wont work

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wrote this simple function which should return value in A1 cell only if something is in A1 of the other sheet cell. Im not sure what I do wrong here. It does not have errors but still wont do the job.

```
function check() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("downloader");
var sh2 = ss.getSheetByName("data");
var dataina1 = sh1.getRange('A1');


if (dataina1 = 5) {
sh2.getRange('B1').setValue("Five");
}

}
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I corrected your problem.

```
//var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID_SPREADSHEET");
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("downloader");
var sh2 = ss.getSheetByName("data");
var value = sh1.getRange("A1").getValue();   // add .getvalue()

  if (value = 5) {
    sh2.getRange('B1').setValue("Five");
  }
```

Worked for me.

Comment: have you tried  -  if (value = 32) { ??  That will still set the value of B1 to Five. In this statement you are assigning 32 to the variable value and any time a variable in an if statement contains a number greater than 0 it will evaluate to true

Comment: The way you have it set up it will always return Five to B1 no matter what you answer in A1

Answer (score 1):

Use the equality operator instead of the assignment operator:

```
if (dataina1 == 5)
```

If you use just a single `=` then you are assigning the value `5` to `dataina1`.

Comment: In future, please explain why your change makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for the comments... but it still does not seem to work, please see the link to spreadsheet. Thank you.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hQai96rwsoKcp1LsAu49YOxOX3yyXJMZd0oHjkgarJI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Then you have more errors in your code. This answer is correct.

Comment: Dataina1 is not correctly set either. Missing getValue. See the other answer which covers that

Answer (score 0):

I modify my script:

It's better like this

```
function myFunction() {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1w-rEm7BcUUnUBcB3kSQX9A0CzryQvkD32UDwA8Eo2FY");
    var sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("downloader");

    // IN THE COLUMN A1 = 5
    var value = sh1.getRange('A1').getValues();


    Logger.log("value of the spreadsheet => "+value);
      if (value == "5") {
        sh1.getRange('B1').setValue("Five");
      }
      else{
      sh1.getRange('B1').setValue("NOT GOOD");
      }

    }
```

LOG :

```
[15-04-29 18:21:42:669 CEST] value of the spreadsheet => 5
```

It's worked

Answer (score 0):

This is classic problem.
You do assignment instead of comparing.

If you do `if(var = 5)` its going to set var to 5 and say its true.

This was very confusing to me at the start but now I remember to use my `==` properly.

Also there is a technique called `Yoda conditions` where you put your constants to the left of the comparison operator: `if (5 == var)`. This will help you to avoid errors and compiler will warn you if you miss second character.